# AddtoAny Share page plugin displaying the URL twice

Tags: html, jquery, share, addtoany

I am using the [AddToAny](https://www.addtoany.com/) plugin on my website. I am getting one issue. When I click on the icon then I am getting the twice URL.

The below is the screenshot of Whatsapp.

**Note**: URL is a dummy.

[image]

I am using the below code on my page.

```
<!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
<div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style">
<a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_linkedin"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_whatsapp"></a>
</div>
<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
<!-- AddToAny END -->
```

Comment: Maybe the plugin firstly displays a title of your page, then the URL? So what is the title (`<title>` tag) of your page. Due to on my demo https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/rNyBzgW I've seen 1 URL: `CodePen Demo https://cdpn.io/cp/internal/boomboom/index.html?key=index.html-8310489b-6ba8-f580-6106-914ffc991065`

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky, You are right. my title was empty that's the reason i was getting this issue. After adding the title my issue got resolved.

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky, I request you please add the answer. I will accept this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin firstly displays a title of your page, then the URL. So check the title (`<title>` tag) of your page. I have just one URL after the page title on my demo: `CodePen Demo https://cdpn.io/cp/internal/boomboom/index.html?key=index.html-8310489b-6ba8-f580-6106-914ffc991065` - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/rNyBzgW

Comment: Thank you for the help. it's working for me.